# Where the error and how to avoid false-character errors

Tags: python

SYNTAX ERROR *(please copy/paste to see)*

```
x = {
"0"​:​"G"​,
"1":"H"
}
```

Tested on line interpreter:

```
>>> x = {
... "0"​:​"G"​
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    "0"​:​"G"​
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But this other (seems the same!) is fine,  *(please copy/paste to see)*

```
x = {
"0":"G",
"1":"H"
}
```

The real-life dictionary is longer and complex, but it is **from a PDF** and I copy/paste to editor (or direct to terminal same result). Perhaps (after comment that confirm) it is a ASCII convertion problem and I need to clean... So que question is *"how to sanitize copy/paste source-code that seeems perfect?"*

---

Tested with both:

- `python --version` = Python 2.7.17
- `python3 --version` = Python 3.6.9

Comment: You've got non-ascii, non-Unicode (as far as I can quickly tell) characters in your first set. They're non-printing, so they don't show up on screen. They do show up in a decent editor. You can avoid this by not entering the non-parseable characters.

Comment: Hi @mpez0, thanks (!) . Now that you confirm that it is "non-ASCII bug", I edited the question... See final notes: how to sanitize it for Python?

Comment: Hum... test copy/paste https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/

Comment: if you use, for example `ascii()` built-in method on your string, you will see that your string contains `\u200b` [Zero Width Space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) You might probably check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522361/python-getting-rid-of-u200b-from-a-string-using-regular-expressions

Comment: What text editor are you using, OP?

Comment: Hi @mpez0, I was using Ubuntu terminal (on software editions  I am using "raw" [Atom](http://atom.io)). Max (below) suggested PyCharm.

Comment: @PeterKrauss, I hope there's a way to configure Atom to at least show all the characters in your file. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment, so I will write this as an answer.

Depending on the text editor you are using, I suggest looking for a package that can do this. Here's one for [Sublime Text](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RemoveNonAsciiChars).

---

There are also some online tools to copy/paste your source and check or sanitize it. Examples:

- http://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover
- https://onlinejsontools.com/

Answer (score 1):

I just tried in 3.6 console - it highlights some odd spacing around first colon and clearly says "SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier". See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAN55.png)

[image]

As @mpez0 already commented - when you copy from PDF (Word etc), a bunch of extra characters tag along.

Comment: Thanks Max!  sorry, I will edit to show how to add image here

Comment: Max, I am using Ubuntu, how to use or install this colored console?

Comment: @PeterKrauss thanks! I'm new - it didn't allow me to paste directly... :)

Comment: You using somethiong as [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) to be a colored console?

Comment: Peter, it's actually PyCharm - I see it's available for Ubuntu as well https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux